# Dynamic number of items in each row using staggeredGridlayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

What I am thinking of is using this [Linear layout, that wrap its content to the next line](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout). Are there any better ways of doing this, may be using `GridLayoutManager`. I also have to show each option in separate line if even one the options is longer than half the width of the screen. Now I have to handle both the cases very separately. Using `FlowLayout` when options are small enough and `RecyclerView` when options are large.

Comment: if you found a solution to that let us know, I'm facing exactly same issue

Comment: Hi did you get any output? I also need the same buddy.